# Android User input to countdown timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm working on a countdown timer with user input on how many seconds to count down.

```
 private void showTimer() {
        myString = ((EditText)editTextTimer).getText().toString();
        int countdownMillis = Integer.parseInt(myString) * 1000;

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        timer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    ((TextView) countdownDisplay).setText("Counting down: " +
                            millisUntilFinished / MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
                    ((TextView) countdownDisplay).setTextSize(25);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                ((TextView)countdownDisplay).setText("Time's Up !");
                ((TextView)countdownDisplay).setTextSize(25);
            }
        }.start();


    }
```

I'm doing this on a fragment. The problem is the text display of the "Time's Up" after I insert the time and click start. When clicking start again the timer will just start to display and countdown. As well the timer sometimes will skip 1 second.

Example user insert 10. 
It will countdown from 10 , 9 , 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1  - 8 is missing.

onCreatView

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countDown, container, false);

        countdownDisplay = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimerLeft);
        editTextTimer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
        startbutton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_start1);

        startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    showTimer();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
```

Declaration

```
 View editTextTimer;
    View startbutton;
    private static final int MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    int SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN;
    View countdownDisplay;
    private CountDownTimer timer;
    String myString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND`and on first try it would 0, as well you initialize `SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN` it only inside `showTimer` function. Go that way:

```
private void showTimer() {
        myString = ((EditText)editTextTimer).getText().toString();
        int countdownMillis = Integer.parseInt(myString) * 1000;
```

Do not pass nothing in function and read value from editText. You can remove `SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN` at all. That's it.